# Do I need to escape single quote for user inputs in classic query?

Tags: soql

If I am already using a classic query like bellow, do I need to use escape single quote for user input?

```
public static List < User > FetchLookUpValues(String searchKeyWord, List<User> ExcludeitemsList) {

    String searchKey = '%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKeyWord) + '%';

    List<string> lstExcludeitems = new List<string>();
    for(User item : ExcludeitemsList ){
        lstExcludeitems.add(item.id);
    }
    
    List < User > lstOfRecords = [select id, Name from User where Name LIKE :searchKey AND Id NOT IN :lstExcludeitems order by createdDate DESC limit 5];

    for (User obj: lstOfRecords) {
        returnList.add(obj);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to copy the Id values out of a sObject list (you can bind to a list directly), no need to use a temporary variable (you're just returning the value), no need to copy the values from a query into a new list, no need to escape quotes (`String.escapeSingleQuotes`) when using inline queries and binding, etc. In general, learning how to be efficient as a developer is something I'd recommend you take the time to do. Less typing means more efficiency.

Comment: `public static User[] FetchLookUpValues(String searchKeyWord, User[] ExcludeitemsList) {searchKeyWord = '%'+searchKeyWord+'%';return [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Name LIKE :searchKeyWord AND ID NOT IN :ExcludeitemsList order by createdDate DESC limit 5];}` Newlines don't transfer in a comment, but you should be able to see how much more efficient you could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no injection vulnerability when you use merge variables (e.g. `:searchKey`). Therefore, no need to escape.